# How to access sessions collection from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using connect-mongo to store sessions in my MongoDb database.I want to find a specific session by id.I've tried with `sessions.find` or `sessionStore.find` but every time i get `Reference error sessions undefined`.How i can access this collection?